# SVN: Add to global ignore unless inside of a folder

Tags: regex, svn, global, svnignore

I'm trying to add a **GLOBAL** filter into TortiseSVN that will ignore Web.config, unless the file is under a "Views" folder.

```
Project
+- Views
|+- Web.config <-- Do not ignore
+-Web.config <-- Ignore
```

I know I can add individual files to the ignore list. But I don't want to do that for all of my projects. So I am looking for a **GLOBAL** filter that will do this.

[image: Global Ignore settings in TortiseSVN]

Answer (score 0):

The svn:ignore property for the Project directory must list Web.config, the one for the Views directory must not. The svn:ignore property is on a per-directory basis.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically looking for a global filter.

Answer (score 0):

The server tracks ignores as svn properties (which means they need to be associated with a particular *file*, and directories *are* files).

[to recursively set ignore lists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html)

```
svn -R propset svn:ignore -F somefile.txt rootdir
```

to stop ignoring something in a particular directory

```
svn propdel svn:ignore path/to/dir
```

Some combination of the above will allow you to ignore items in the entire tree, while ignoring just a bit less in the right directory.

There is no such thing as configuring a pattern matching ignore to some directory path, as it would be very hard to resolve when the ignore applies / stop applying to the actual files without triggering non-user initiated modifications of the directories above the file.  SVN (wisely) decided it was a revision control system, and not a revision automation system.

File based revision control systems have no such qualms, but they have different issues, like inability to properly handle histories of file renames / copies / movement / etc.